# JSP request.getParameter() always returning null for dropdown selection

Tags: html, forms, jsp, drop-down-menu, request

Please what am I doing wrong in the code below?

The jsp selection value is coming as null. This jsp has 3 inputs(form_date(date input), to_date(date input) and link_name(dropdown) input) all wrapped in a form tag. When passed to a servlet, `String link_name = request.getParameter("link_name")` and `String form_date = request.getParameter("form_date")` have their correct date values. However, `String link_name = request.getParameter("link_name")` is always having `null` value on the servlet.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%String link_name = request.getParameter("link_name");
String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/";
String database = "orclpdb";
String userid = "";
String password = "";
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rsIndex_1 = null;%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
 charset=ISO-8859-1"><title>IP Core Downtime</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href=
  "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script 
   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({changeMonth: 
    true, changeYear: true});
            $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 
      "yy-mm-dd");
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker({changeMonth: 
     true, changeYear: true});
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 
    "yy-mm-dd");
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h2 align="center">IP Core Downtime</h2>

    <form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}
    /KPIResultServlet">
        <div align="center">
            <%
                try {
     connection =DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl 
       + database, userid, password);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sqlIndex_1 = "select * from aatestuser.link_data";
                    rsIndex_1 = statement.executeQuery(sqlIndex_1);
            %>
            Name : <select  name="link_name">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select Link</option>
                <%
                    while (rsIndex_1.next()) {%>

       <option value=
      <%=rsIndex_1.getString("circuit_id")%>><%=rsIndex_1.getString
      ("link_name")%>
        </option>
                <%
                        }
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
     out.println("Driver caused Exception : " + e.getMessage() + "");
                    }
                %>
            </select> 
            <br>
            <br>
     <p> From Date: <input type="text" 
    name="form_date" id="datepicker"></p>
     <p> To Date:  <input type="text" 
     name="to_date" id="datepicker1"></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br>
        </div>
    </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

It is required for `form_date`, `to_date` and `link_name` input to be passed to the servlet's request.getParameter. However,  link_name is coming as `null`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant:The jsp selection value is coming as null. This jsp has 3 inputs(form_date(date input), to_date(date input) and link_name(dropdown) input) all wrapped in a form tag. When passed to a servlet, String to_date = request.getParameter("to_date") and String form_date = request.getParameter("form_date") have their correct date values.However, String link_name = request.getParameter("link_name") is always having ''null'' value on the servlet.

Comment: what does `<%=rsIndex_1.getString("circuit_id")%>` have in it ,check in your element tab if you are using chrome ..does it show any value or not  ?

Comment: Hi Swati, I checked it on chrome. <%=rsIndex_1.getString("circuit_id")%> was showing "null".

Comment: That means you are not getting anything from your table . check for connection also if column name is right or not .

Comment: Thanks Swati, I've now fixed the problem. I had to change "circuit_id" to "link_name". It is no longer showing null. That was the solution.

Comment: Side note: don't put JDBC code (actually, any business logic code) into JSP. Use MVC pattern, load data in a servlet, and use JSP only to display them. Will be much easier to debug then.